# Sorting a List using bubble sort

Tags: java, class, variables

```
import java.lang.Object;
import java.util.List;
 class Sort{
  public static int bubble(List<String> sorted) {
    int count=0; int i=sorted.size();
    boolean changed = true;
    while(changed && i>0) {
      changed = false;
      for(int j=1; j<i; j++) {
        if(sorted.get(j).toUpperCase().compareTo(sorted.get(j-1).toUpperCase())<0) {
          String s=sorted.get(j);
          sorted.set(j,sorted.get(j-1));
          sorted.set(j-1, s);
          changed = true;
        }   
      }
      count++;
      i--;
    }
    return count;
  }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
class SortTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> sorted, list;
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    sorted = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] arr= {"Cat", "Dog", "Hat", "Apple", "Zipper"};

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      list.add(arr[i]);
      sorted.add(arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println();
    int count = Sort.int(sorted);
    System.out.println("Sorted in "+count+" passes");
    System.out.println(sorted);
  }
}
```

this program is supposed to sort my list of words in alphabetical order and when i run the program it prints out the same way i typed it.
Also, count does not work in class SortTest and i don't know why

Comment: does you code even compile? you can't have `int()` int is a keyword

Comment: Whty are you doing this? The bubble sort is the most inefficient sorting method known to computer science short of dropping the card deck on the floor, and sorting a list rather than an array ditto.

Comment: @EJP: This is what I dislike the most about the Stackoverflow community, not to offend you personally, but what does it matter to you whether he uses bubble sort or quick sort? And why are you assuming that this is production code? I feel people in this community specifically, should just answer reasonable questions such as this, to the point and stop questioning the question itself, thereby discouraging beginners and amateurs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use 
Sort.bubble(list);
this works fine i run in my PC

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the function to sort the list in your program. In the below code, you are adding the elements in the array to both the list and the sorted list.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      list.add(arr[i]);
      sorted.add(arr[i]);
}
```

Thereafter you are going ahead and printing sorted, but sorted has the same content as list.

In order to sort list, call the bubble function with your list as parameter, the code could be something along the lines of :

```
Sort SortObj = new Sort(); 
sorted = SortObj.bubble(list);
System.out.println(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that stands out would be:

```
int count = Sort.int(sorted);
```

Should probably be:

```
int count = Sort.bubble(sorted);
```